# how to design a website in openerp version 7

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, odoo-8

I want to design a website in Odoo version 8. But now I, want to design a new website using version 7. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible, if you just want to use standard method. Because many changes in api and sfructure are made from openerp7 to odoo8, including web base modules. So if you want to use website and web modules of odoo8 you need to use verion 8. If you have to use version 7 so then you need to rebuild website module on your way !

Answer (score 0):

The is no standard website module for openerp 7. So if you want to design a website for openerp 7 you should backport whe website module from odoo 8 to openerp 7. You're better off to use Odoo 8. (it has more functionality anyhow)